# Need to install Oracle Express 11g Release 2 on a Windows 7 64-bit laptop

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, windows, oracle-xe

I need the Oracle 11g Release 2 sample schemas (HR, OE, etc.) in order to do most of the available online tutorials.  I was hoping to install Oracle Express Edition on my Windows 7 laptop to get these; but I have never heard of anybody successfully installing Oracle XE on a 64-bit Windows platform.

Is there a version of Oracle XE 11g R2 available for Windows 7?  And if so, could you please point me to it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose you can download the pre-built virtual Machines (VMs) provided by Oracle. They only need Oracle Virtual Box in order to check them out (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

You can download them here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/community/developer-vm/index.html

This is the best solution for learning Oracle DB, without actually messing up your system.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so.  Because it's free, Oracle seems to have limited it to 32 bit to prevent it from being used for business purposes.